# IIS 7 remote administration via C#

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008, nant, remote-administration

I have been looking into the Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll and the ServerManager class, trying to control our Windows Server 2008 IIS 7 instance.

I have enabled remote administration and can connect via the IIS remote administration tool. However, when I try and use the following, I cannot connect:

```
ServerManager.OpenRemote(serverName);
```

This class does not allow me to specify a username and password on the remote IIS 7 server, as the IIS remote administrator tool does.

This is all being called via our build process using [NAnt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAnt).

How do others control their remote IIS 7 server as part of their [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a [WCF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation) service in the end, which runs on the remote machine as a service. The service runs under a local account with administrator rights so that the local IIS instance on that machine can be changed.

From my NAnt script I have a series of custom tasks that communicate to the WCF service and change IIS settings as required.

As this is an internal dev environment I am not too concerned about security and the actual changes to IIS I am allowed are very basic.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to run the application under a domain user (Active Directory user) that has the right permissions to change the configuration files.

Windows authentication will do the rest.

Comment: What permissions are required? I assume write permissions to the folder: %systemroot%\System32\inetsrv\Config

Answer (score 1):

As [Oded says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478283/iis-7-remote-administration-via-c-sharp/5478343#5478343), you need Active Directory to be able to open a connection to a remote server using `ServerManager`.

Assuming you have administrator [RDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) access server there is an alternative which is to use [WinRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Remote_Management) and Remote PowerShell (works best with PowerShell 2.0 which comes with the latest version of WinRM) in your build scripts:

> [Windows Remote Management Command-Line Tool (Winrm.cmd)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781778%28WS.10%29.aspx)

To quickly configure WinRM for two machines that are not in a domain:

**Client:**

```
winrm quickconfig  (just say yes)
winrm set winrm/config/Client/Auth '@{Basic="true"}'
:: Only do this next line if not using HTTPS
winrm set winrm/config/Client '@{AllowUnencrypted="true"}'
winrm set winrm/config/Client '@{TrustedHosts="hostname_or_ip"}'
```

**Server:**

```
winrm quickconfig (just say yes)
winrm set winrm/config/Service/Auth '@{Basic="true"}'

:: See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019527 regarding https
winrm quickconfig -transport:https

:: Only do this if not using HTTPS AND you are happy about sending credentials
:: in clear text.
winrm set winrm/config/Service '@{AllowUnencrypted="true"}'
```

Now there are some caveats. WinRM will punch a hole in Windows Firewall for ports 5985 and 5986 for the listener (if running [Windows Server 2003](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2003) it'll use port 80 and 443). This may not be to your liking and you'd probably best speak to your network admins about how to secure that.

Once you have WinRM configured you'll need user account configured on the remote server that is a member of the administrators group. Once done you can then test. On the build server:

```
# the following line will prompt for a username and password, enter the name of the account
# you just configured on the IIS box
$cred = Get-Credential

# next test the connection
Test-WSMan -ComputerName <server_name_or_ip> -Authentication default `
           -Credential $cred
```

If all is good you should see the following response:

```
wsmid           : http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/identity/1/wsmanidentity.x
                  sd
ProtocolVersion : http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/1/wsman.xsd
ProductVendor   : Microsoft Corporation
ProductVersion  : OS: 6.1.7600 SP: 0.0 Stack: 2.0
```

The next thing is to connect to a remote PowerShell session:

```
Enter-PSSession <server_name_or_ip_address> -Authentication default -Credential $cred
```

If this is successful you should have a PowerShell prompt on the remote machine.

Using Remote PowerShell you can then load the WebAdministration Provider for PowerShell and manipulate many aspects of IIS to your hearts content:

> [Web Administration (IIS) Provider for Windows PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee909471%28WS.10%29.aspx)

To connect to the remote server you need to provide a `PSCredential` object. As mentioned above you would provide this using:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
```

However, this always demands some interaction from the keyboard to provide a username and password. Obviously this is no good for automated CI.

You can however store the password in a file. To do this run the following just once (or whenever the password changes):

```
read-host -assecurestring | convertfrom-securestring | out-file C:\securestring.txt
```

Then when you need to create your `PSCredential` to authenticate to the remote server:

```
$username = "deployment_user"
$password = cat C:\securestring.txt | convertto-securestring
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
         -argumentlist $username, $password

$serverNameOrIp = "192.168.1.1"
Enter-PSSession $serverNameOrIp -Authentication default -Credential $cred
```

The above script was sourced from the following blog entry but I've duplicated to preserve here just in case that article goes dark:

> [Using PSCredentials without a prompt - GeeksWithBlogs (archive.org)](https://web.archive.org/web/20110828112649/http://geekswithblogs.net/Lance/archive/2007/02/16/106518.aspx)

Anyway, so once you're connected to the remote server you can issue further commands such as:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
CD IIS:\Sites
```

And so on.

Most of the above should be approached with caution if this machine is internet facing and the only way to access is via the internet. If this is the case consider restricting the WinRM ports to VPN only.

Comment: The last link is (effectively) broken. It redirects to *[Geekswithblogs.net, the End of an Era](http://julian.farm/geekswithblogs/?url=/mtreadwell/archive/2004/06/06/6123.aspx)*.

Comment: @PeterMortensen sorted. I though the point of anyone being able to edit was that the link could have been pointed at archive.org without needing my intervention ;)